# Interconversion between decimal and any other base-n number system

Tags: ruby, math, decimal, number-systems

I have written some general functions to convert between decimal and any other base-n number system(n<=36 for now) and vice-versa. Don't want to make things messy here so i have posted the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/internal-ganimi/source/browse/trunk/base_converter.rb).

Could anybody suggest any better way for this? May be more effective and Rubyish?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's already the `to_s` method on `Numeric` and the `to_i` method on `String` to convert back:

```
irb(main):013:0> 10.to_s(36)
=> "a"
irb(main):014:0> "a".to_i(36)
=> 10
```

Comment: +1 - Wow!!.. i didn't see it... that's amazing... thanks.
But i wasn't looking for that... I was just trying my hands on some usual problems. Do you have any suggestions for refactoring it?

Comment: 5001.to_s(36).to_i(10)
=> 3

Answer (score 0):

Check out Rosetta Code: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Non-decimal_radices/Convert#Ruby